# Variable mock responses depending on url hash

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code to mock responses for 'App' in my development environment:

```
<script>
    var AppDev = angular.module('AppDev', ['App', 'ngMockE2E' ]);


    AppDev.run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/call').respond({"somekey" : "5000"});
        //$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/call').respond(422, { 13 : "oh shit!"});
        //$httpBackend.whenGET('/api/call').respond(500, "my error text");
    });
</script>
```

I would like to make this a switch somehow, based on external input like a click in that page to set the url hash.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `respond()` method can also take a function as its argument, and it will pass the request url into the function, so you can parse the url and do whatever you want with it. For example:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/api\/call.*/).respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {

    /*
     * The request URL is available, so you can do whatever you want, such as the
     * following:
     */
    if (url matches condition 1) {
        return [200, {"somekey" : "5000"}];
    } else if (url matches condition 2) {
        return [422, { 13 : "Oops"}];
    } else {
        return [500, "my error text"];
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting feature, but not what I am looking for. The requesting urls from the functions themselves don't change, but I would like to be able to change the reaction of the mock backend by for example clicking a button in my page which holds this code

Comment: That's also achievable by modifying my answer a little bit. Inside of using url as the condition, you can just use a flag variable, something like `AppDev.backendMode`. Then, in your button click handler, set `AppDev.backendMode` to whatever you need.

Comment: Think I'm going in the wrong direction here; the backend url needs to be set when the app loads, which can only be done at init time of the controller, so I guess I can only do this using the url at load time and not with a button